# Syntax error with SQLite query in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create a new SQLite database in Android.
Here is my onCreate method:

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "eventList.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "event_table";
public static final String COL1 = "ID";
public static final String COL2 = "EVENTNAME";
public static final String COL3 = "UNIXTIMESTAMP";
public static final String COL4 = "PARTICIPANTS";
public static final String COL5 = "LOCATION";
public static final String COL6 = "LOCATIONNAME";
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCRIMENT, "
            + " EVENTNAME TEXT, UNIXTIMESTAMP INTEGER, PARTICIPANTS TEXT, LOCATION TEXT, LOCATIONNAME TEXT)";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(createTable);
}
```

This is throwing a syntax error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCRIMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE event_table(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCRIMENT,  EVENTNAME TEXT, UNIXTIMESTAMP INTEGER, PARTICIPANTS TEXT, LOCATION TEXT, LOCATIONNAME TEXT)

Please do note that PARTICIPANTS is going to be a custom object, and LOCATION is going to be a LatLng object.

How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in

```
 String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCRIMENT, "
```

Note that `AUTOINCRIMENT` should be spelt `AUTOINCREMENT`

plus ID should be _id
Also, as you have gone to the trouble of setting up constants why not use them to save on further potential typos? e.g.
Instead of

```
+ " EVENTNAME TEXT
```

Why not use

```
+ COL2 + " TEXT
```

etc...

Could I suggest you read up on how to create databases [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)
It is a superb tutorial and shows best practices

Answer (score 2):

`ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCRIMENT` is incorrect it should be `ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

However, coding AUTOINCREMENT, is probably best not coded at all, as per [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) . ID will still be a unique identifier.

You may also find it advantageous to use **_id** instead of **ID** as the column name. Sometimes **_id** is required e.g. as for `CursorAdapters`.

So I'd suggest using `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "eventList.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "event_table";
public static final String COL1 = "ID";
public static final String COL2 = "EVENTNAME";
public static final String COL3 = "UNIXTIMESTAMP";
public static final String COL4 = "PARTICIPANTS";
public static final String COL5 = "LOCATION";
public static final String COL6 = "LOCATIONNAME";
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + " EVENTNAME TEXT, UNIXTIMESTAMP INTEGER, PARTICIPANTS TEXT, LOCATION TEXT, LOCATIONNAME TEXT)";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(createTable);
}
```

I Think Your error in  spelling mistake
 Replace  AUTOINCRIMENT to AUTOINCREMENT.